# Syncano Android SDK - adding user to group

Tags: android, syncano

Syncano docs specifies that adding user to group is done by:

```
Response<GroupMembership> response = syncano.addUserToGroup(group.getId(), user.getId()).send();
```

But I don't see method 'addUserToGroup' in latest version (4.0.6). What is new way of adding user to group?

Answer (score 2):

Methods available in Syncano class were divided to two groups. Those in Syncano class and those in SyncanoDashboard class. Assumption is that methods from Syncano class are available for single users. SyncanoDashboard is something for administrator. These methods will not work on user key.

Instead of using Syncano class, just use SyncanoDashboard. It extends Syncano.

```
SyncanoDashboard syncano = new SyncanoDashboard(API_KEY, INSTANCE_NAME);
```

Comment: So is there a way to automatically add user to particular group? If possible by code on client (Android), if not some action on server?